# Number of motors RWD Tesla

Tags: tesla

Tesla always speaks about one motor on its **Rear Wheel Drive** Model S car. But every time I see a picture of the rear axle as in the search https://www.google.pt/search?q=tesla+bottom+motor&safe=off&tbm=isch , it seems it has got there two motors.

[image]

So how many motors does it have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is the motor which is an AC motor. The center of it is a simple gearbox. Because an electric motor can be throttled and can run up to a speed far beyond what a gasoline driven engine can run, there doesn't need to be a transmission. Then to the other side is a **three phase tri-pole inverter** which converts the DC battery power into AC power to run the motor. (You may have something similar which you use to power a laptop or other A/C using devices in your vehicle, but this one is on a whole different scale.) [This *How it's Made Dream Cars*](http://youtu.be/ZOriitPjlcw) episode (S02E10) explains how everything is put together.

Answer (score 5):

It is a single motor.

A good source of information is [here](http://insideevs.com/video-primer-tesla-model-s-electric-motor/).  About 15 seconds in, they describe that one side is the electric motor.  The other side is the power electronics.  The middle is the gearbox.  I believe from looking closely at the video that the slightly smaller side (the right in the picture in the question) is the motor.